# OSPF p2p Network type

Tags: cisco, routing, ospf

Imagine this scenario:

```
R1-------R2
```

`R1`'s serial 1 is connected to `R2`'s serial 1, it's a simple p2p link. Quite simple, right?

When I changed the network type on the both sides to non-broadcast, for any unreasonable reason, the adjacency dropped and everything collapsed :) I know about OSPF network types and am also well aware of the troubleshooting process. I issued almost any show/debug command; everything mostly matches on both sides: timers, area, etc. But it doesn't work, why? How do I get it working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you change the type to non-broadcast, you prevent the routers from multicasting their hellos (and everything else).  Since they can't send hellos to each other, the adjacency drops.

As a troubleshooting hint, you should have seen that in the debugs -- OSPF was not sending hellos out that interface.

You can fix this by explicitly defining the neighbors using the neighbor statement under ospf

```
router ospf 1
neighbor 1.1.1.1
```

Hellos and LSAs will be unicast to the defined neighbor.